# SOQL embedded select question

Tags: soql, community, dynamic-soql

In our implimentation an Opportunity has a *.1 relationship with accounts and a *.1 relationship with brokers.
An account is an entry to Object Account with Type = 'Customer'. A broker is an entry to Object Account with Type = 'Broker/Consultant'.

In a query I'm trying to write (this will be used in Qlikview to interigate SFDC Database) I'm trying to get a list of all opportunitues, and the owners of their accounts and brokers.
So something like this (but obviously doesn't work)

```
SELECT AccountId,
     Id,
     Broker_Account__c,
     Name,
     OwnerId,
     (SELECT OwnerId FROM Account WHERE Type = 'Customer'), -- thinking Account.Id = Opportunity.AccountId should be in the where statement here
     (SELECT OwnerId FROM Account WHERE Type = 'Broker/Consultant') -- thinking Account.Id = Opportunity.Broker_Account__c should be in the where statement here
FROM Opportunity
```

Any thoughts on how to go around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to use a subquery, but I think you've got the data model upside-down. The Opportunity is a child of the Account, therefore you'd want to use the child-to-parent query. 
If your Opportunity has two lookup fields to Account (one for the customer lookup and one for the broker lookup), you could write your query as follows

> SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId, Account.OwnerId, Broker_Account__r.OwnerId FROM Opportunity

This is assuming that the standard Account lookup will always refer to one of Type = "Customer" and the Broker_Account__c will always refer to one of Type = "Broker/Consultant". If that is not always the case then we may need to select a little more information for later interpretation and add a permissive filtering cause such as:

> SELECT Id, Name, OwnerId, Account.OwnerId, Account.Type, Broker_Account__r.OwnerId, Broker_Account__r.Type FROM Opportunity 
>   WHERE (Account.Type = "Customer" OR Broker_Account__r.Type = "Broker/Consultant")

Comment: Thank you, I believe that gets it!! I'm a SOQL newb, so what's the __r doing here?

Comment: The __r stands for the relationship. It allows you to access the record related through the field (__c) and pull fields from that record into your query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be trying to retrieve the data like so.  The type of query you had pulls Accounts in with the Opportunities nested into them (very terrible in data extraction tools btw).

```
SELECT AccountId,
         Id,
         Broker_Account__c,
         Name,
         OwnerId,
         Account.OwnerId,
         Account.Owner.Name,
         Account.Type
    FROM Opportunity where AccountId in (SELECT AccountId FROM Account WHERE Type in ('Customer','Broker/Consultant'))
```

I suggest this link for a better understanding of some of the more complicated queries:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL.htm

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to use subqueries in the WHERE clause

Comment: Yes you are.  It is a left-inner join.  You can learn more here:   https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com

Comment: The key is that the return data on the subquery has to be of the data type Id (no string unfortunately :().  Also, they have to be Ids of the same SObject type (obviously), or a polymorphic that also includes that type (e.g. OwnerId).